# Prove using mathematical induction that $n^2 > n+1$ for all $n \ge 2$

Tags: inequality, induction

I have proved for the initial case $P(2)$ that this is true, but I'm stuck at substituting in $n=k+1$, $(k+1)^2 > (k+1)+1$ = $k^2 + 2k + 1 > k+2$, where do I go from here or have I made a mistake?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: also apologies about the greater than or equal to sign, not sure how to do that yet, I'm new, if someone could fix that it would be appreciated.

Comment: We have $k\ge 2$ and $k^2+2k+1=k(k+2)+1$... Can you continue?

Comment: @AidanLeith Here is a tutorial of MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @abiessu I don't understand how you can get $k(k+2)+1 > k+2$, we were only really taught induction for equalities.

Comment: Note $k(k+2)\ge k+2$ whenever $k\ge 1$...

Comment: Advice for the future: do _not_ use the equals sign ($=$) to indicate that two statements are equivalent. You inadvertently wrote in your question that $(k+1)+1 = k^2 + 2k + 1$ (which I know you did not mean--but it came out looking that way nevertheless). You can use $\iff$ to indicate equivalence; in cases like this it may be even better to just use words.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $k^2>k+1$. Then

$(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1>k+1+2k+1=3k+2>k+2,$ because $k>0$.

Comment: This is correct. On pretty much every induction question, you need to utilize the assumption for P(k).

Comment: Could you just show more steps on how you got to each point?

Comment: @AidanLeith $k^2+2k+1>k+1+2k+1$, because $k^2>k+1$ by an inductive assumption. $3k+2>k+2$, because $k\ge 2>0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky but how did you get the LHS to equal $3k+2$.

Comment: @AidanLeith Which expression you mean by LHS?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Left Hand Side

Comment: @AidanLeith Which Left Hand Side, $k+1+2k+1$ or $k^2+2k+1$?